# In Qt, how to customize a QTabWidget as below via qss?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

I'm trying to customize a QTabWidget as below. But I don't know how to show the line marked by red color as below in qss.

[image]

Comment: As background image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to style two different subcontrols of QTabWidget: pane and tab-bar.

Give pane a top border and a negative top:

```
QTabWidget::pane{
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Now the selected tab of the tab-bar:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected{
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

Please note that the selected tab can not have transparent background, otherwise the pane top border will show up behind it (here I provided a light gray background, just as an example).